Do we really need [imaging]? It is not programming!
I just ran into a tag imaging that shouldn't exist in my opinion.
The tag wiki says:

Anything related to digital imaging, i.e. the theory, the technology and the techniques about acquiring, representing, processing and rendering digital images. This is a term with a rather broad meaning: consider using a more specific tag if it applies to your use case (e.g. use [image-processing] tag if the question is specifically about processing and not rendering).

It is indeed broad. We have a tag image for questions about storing and displaying images, and a tag image-processing for questions about processing images. The aspects of imaging not covered by those two tags is image acquisition, which is not related to programming (image acquisition is about CCDs, lenses, etc.).
This tag has a total of 469 questions as of today, most of which should be tagged with image or image-processing instead. So far this year, it has only been used 8 times. Last year it was used 9 times. Definitely a low-traffic tag.

Answers to the standard four questions:

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The term is very broad, thereby not really describing the contents of the question. There are much bigger tags covering different aspects of what [imaging] covers.
Also, it seems that some people have used it to refer to disk images, which is an unrelated concept.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The aspects of it that are on-topic are covered by more specific tags, other aspects are not on-topic.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I guess it might, but not if one of the more specific tags is also used.

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. It can refer to the process of acquiring images and getting information out of them, and it can refer to the process of copying the structure and data of a computer disk into a file or other disk.

There is also a tag [tag:medical-imaging], which is the same but limited to medical applications, as if that changed anything about the programming aspects of it. Can that be included in the same burnination effort?

...And there's also a tag [tag:medical]. Sigh.

A [[meta-tag:burnination-request]] has requirements for the post, you should [edit] your post here to meet those requirements.

[Imag(in)ing] a world without this tag

@CrisLuengo the description for medical  reads What is medicine? Are they asking us?

@InsertCheesyLine - That seems like a stackoverflow issue; not a problem with that tag. It seems that each tag has a short and a long descriptive tag, and the description is the first sentence of the long tag - which is a header in this case (and the description gives an answer)

You can also see a really funny example of this issue in the medical tag that reads in full: "Anything related to digital imaging, i.e." (and nothing more) - basically using the first part of the wiki - and stopping at the dot.

Just saying. If we're going to micromanage imaging away, image should also be on the chopping block. Image-processing is better. If something is tagged "java image-processing", I know what I'm getting myself into (but then again, the title should have already done that...). If it is tagged "java image", I am probably going to click because I have no idea what the question is going to be about.

@Gimby [image] is about storing and displaying images, which is distinct from image processing. [image] gets all the questions about GUIs and web sites and databases and so on that I'm not at all interested in. [image-processing] is a 1/3rd the size of [image], and gets the questions that are interesting to me. Combining the two tags would mean I'd have to wade through 4 times as many questions to find the same few interesting ones. I could see splitting [image] into [image-display] and [image-storage], but I wouldn't appreciate merging it into [image-processing].

How about just  getting rid of image/imaging? Removing a ambiguous tag doesn't mean that it has to be replaced with another.

I retag questions to use [image] instead of [image-processing] whenever people use images, but don't do [image-processing]. examples: showing an image in a GUI/web page, converting images between different (compressed) formats, ... people interested in [image-processing] are not usually interested in web development or people curating their photo collection.

I don't see much utility in [imaging]. it greatly overlaps with [image-processing] and [computer-vision].

@ChristophRackwitz what prevents you from removing the tag and be done? What makes image better for the question?

@Braiam If I want to find a question to answer, I start with a tag search for the technologies I am most familiar with. All of the people I have discussed this with do the same thing, so I presume this is very common. Removing the [image] tag means that the people following the [image] tag will not see that question, and so will not be able to answer it. [image] is not an ambiguous tag, it’s useful and used by many people. [imaging] sounds similar, but it’s a different concept. Don’t confound the two.

@Braiam [image] isn't being discussed here though. I'm not interested in that tag but maybe others are. I often add tags that I'm not personally interested in, just so it's tagged appropriately. if someone else thinks the question needs a different tag more badly, they can always bump any of the existing tags out of the list of five. perhaps I don't understand your question. please elaborate.

@CrisLuengo correct, that means that you should avoid with all your strengths any tag that isn't obviously about something that is programming, because this is a programming site, therefore all topics should be around it. Image/imaging can mean a thousand things, from digitalization/scanning, photography, picture storage, picture visualization, printing, compression, fun stuff, etc. I would avoid such tag since just to me, means at least 7 completely different things, some of which I have varying amount of knownledge. So, why would you go with that tag, instead of matlab or python?

@ChristophRackwitz "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories" I won't use any tag that doesn't fit that purpose. As Cris puts it, he doesn't search for image-processing on languages other than matlab/python/opencv. From Cris perspective, we could obliterate such tag and he would be able to still find questions to answer based on title + tags.

@Braiam I did not say that at all. I do search for questions using [image-processing], I can answer such questions no matter what language or library the asker is using. Likewise, some people will search for questions using [image], and they'll be able to answer such questions in any language and with many different libraries. This post here is about [imaging], which is too broad for any one person being an expert in all of what it covers. Consequently, [imaging] has only 263 watchers, whereas [image] has 4.1k and [image-processing] 11.3k.

sure we could argue over [image] as well, but that's not the topic of this discussion, so let's not.

@Braiam I can't clearly tell what your position is. my impression is that you seem to be paraphrasing other people's positions, potentially using interpretative leeway to distort them, perhaps using the "somebody's wrong on the internet" principle to elicit refutations. no, we are not going to "obliterate" useful tags. I smell rhetoric tricks.

the [image] tag may serve as a "stop" for people who think the question needs some tag involving "image", so that they don't just apply the next best thing ([image-processing]) to it when it's not appropriate. they'd see the [image] tag on the question and be content with it. -- again, that's beside the topic. the topic is [imaging]. I haven't seen anyone argue for that tag, so isn't it safe to say we can live happily without it?

if the [imaging] tag is to be removed, some people might desire a [disk-imaging] tag. there are a few questions that deal with disk images/drive images (imaging of installed operating systems, partitions, entire disks). the [disk] tag already exists, so that might be a suitable target. common companions to [imaging] appear to be .NET technology (system.windows.media.imaging, windows.graphics.imaging) and DICOM (medical imaging).

@ChristophRackwitz I didn’t realize that. You’re saying the tag is ambiguous. Even more reason to get rid of it.

perhaps the "disk imaging" crowd ought to be shooed off to [su] or [sf] because the questions I saw almost always related to system administration. just one dealt with Android, but even there the question was on how to use a crippled dd on the device, once again to image the system's storage. none of that relates to programming as such. it's tool use/administration. questions asking how to use ffmpeg are off-topic, and some other questions asking how to use other command line tools should be off-topic but are tolerated due to historical reasons.

@ChristophRackwitz no, I'm just noticing how in context, many of the proposals don't deal with the obvious answer of "none of these tags should exists". Sadly, people took the "one tag per post" to the extreme, when all these tags have the same problem: they aren't unique to programming at all. Imaging, image, image-* and *-imaging all would classify as either off topic (like the disk variant) or too vague and badly defined ("image processing"). If we are going to solve an issue with imaging, we should not make another problematic tag harder to tackle.

The solution to [imaging] is to remove it, not to replace it with similar tags, but remove it. If there are posts that don't have proper tags, then we apply the proper ones.

I disagree. programming doesn't exist in a vacuum. it solves real world problems. domain vocabulary intrudes, rightfully. that's why we have [image-processing]. it requires programming (library use) but also domain expertise. that's one example out of surely thousands of things that are on-topic for [so]. "the problem isn't pure programming" does not make something off-topic. nor is anyone qualified to solve an image processing problem purely because they know how to write a loop or call a function. those tags have merit, they are useful. concepts can't be partitioned. concepts overlap.

@Braiam "python" is not unique to programming either. Should we get rid of that tag too? I think you're just trying to push people's buttons, you're not trying to help improve the site.

@CrisLuengo that argument is so old it's not funny. Just search for the response I gave 5 years ago and not waste my time. Image is not a topic that can be asked in isolation here, tags are not hashtags either. Tags are topics that you can ask, you can ask about python the programming language. If you ask about other python, that's not the problem of the tag, however. With image, it is the problem with the tag.

BTW, nice title, it's funny that you seem to agree to make a joke.

"Image is not a topic that can be asked in isolation here".  But it is. No matter how you spin it, encoding an image is a programming issue, displaying an image is a programming issue. The things covered by that tag are on topic here. And that is not the topic of this post. [imaging] and [image] are two separate, distinct tags. Please stop conflating the two. We are discussing [imaging] here. Read the tag descriptions if you are confused about what they mean.

@Braiam Also, LOL on "Just search for the response I gave 5 years ago". That's a needle in a haystack.

@CrisLuengo yeah, because I'm tired of the same low effort argument that doesn't change anything. Get better arguments, and you will get effort from me.

Oh, hey, literally as a response to you

Tags are a "word or phrase that describes the topic of the question", but the topic of the question has to still be something that is within the context of "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" so that users on the site know with which kind of tools they are solving a problem practically. Imaging is not it. Not only has usages outside of programming, the concepts applied within programming aren't most born out of it. Imaging techniques are independent of tools, there are better criteria to determine whenever or not I should be able to answer a question a priory and remove those which I would not be able to. If I know opencv, a tool to recognize and identify features in data that represents images, I would not be able to do so in any other tool that does the same things even if I understand the concepts.
When using tags we shouldn't only think about the people that have knowledge, but also serve for the people that don't have knowledge. Tags are the main way to apply knowledge based discrimination, because its flat structure answerers can on a glance determine what category of questions they would be able to effectively and effortlessly provide feedback. This is the systems way to connect with experts. If someone wants to know about tools that are adjacent to their knowledge (boofcv, etc) there are better sites for it, like forums and wikis.
